# managing the phone number validation exploits using regex

Tags: php, regex

I have written regex to validate the US and UK phone numbers. It is working fine but not for all case.

like it should not filter legitimate numbers like : `12345678` or `123456789`, `1989` etc. Probably I need to validate each area code of `US UK` for first three digits. Am I right?

Here is the list of all UK area code: http://www.area-codes.org.uk/ big list. Do I need to include all of them in regex?

Issue: it should also filter exploits like this : 203453seven67

how it could be done?

Here is the example : http://ideone.com/zwzmKU

REgex:

```
$pattern = '((^\(?(?:(?:0(?:0|11)\)?[\s-]?\(?|\+)44\)?[\s-]?\(?(?:0\)?[\s-]?\(?)?|0)(?:\d{2}\)?[\s-]?\d{4}[\s-]?\d{4}|\d{3}\)?[\s-]?\d{3}[\s-]?\d{3,4}|\d{4}\)?[\s-]?(?:\d{5}|\d{3}[\s-]?\d{3})|\d{5}\)?[\s-]?\d{4,5}|8(?:00[\s-]?11[\s-]?11|45[\s-]?46[\s-]?4\d))(?:(?:[\s-]?(?:x|ext\.?\s?|\#)\d+)?)$)|(\(?[2-9][0-8][0-9]\)?[-. ]?[0-9]{3}[-. ]?[0-9]{4}))';
```

Comment: Are you trying to validate for something that's not in the [NANP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_American_Numbering_Plan)? If you can use NANP only, then `^(?:(?:\+?1\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?)?(?:(\s*([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-8]1|[2-9][02-8][02-9]‌​)\s*)|([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-8]1|[2-9][02-8][02-9]))\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?)?([2-9]1[02-‌​9]|[2-9][02-9]1|[2-9][02-9]{2})\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?([0-9]{4})$`.

Comment: thanks. No, not only which belongs to NANP, but all US and UK numbers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For making sure the phone number is correct, avoid using regex and use some standard library which can help you with the phone number validations.

I suggest https://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/

Comment: does it validate all US and UK numbers? any experience with it?

Comment: It validates the US numbers perfectly well. There were some UK number series lacking, but afaik they updated the data. So if you use the latest version it should work for most UK numbers.

Comment: Also there is maintained version of libphone that we use here : https://github.com/practo/libphonenumber-for-php    which does take care of UK numbers

Comment: But I need faster response. Is it faster then regex?

Comment: You won't be able to validate numbers or update your regex every time new series of numbers are bumped. The library takes care of it. To answer your question, it will be slower than regex, but how much, I don't know.